# How to Reassign value to variable in Django template through filters

Tags: python, django, django-templates, variable-assignment

I have an xml object that I am looping to print in template. It is detailing of items with their tax rate. so after printing all items I need sum of those tax rate values.  I am trying to sum up that value in template. I have created filter named updatevariable, it is working and doing sum up but issue is due to loose of old sum it just returns latest value rather than whole sum up. SO I need a way to reassign TotalTax with sum up value from filter.
this is example of output needed:

Tax-1      16

Tax-2      18

Tax-3      2

TotalTax = 36

```
    {% with TotalTax=0  %}
        {% if taxRateDetailing %}
            {% for item in taxRateDetailing%}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{item.1.text}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{item.4.text}}
                        {{TotalTax|updatevariable:item.4.text}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Total Tax
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{TotalTax}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                Tax
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{defaultSalesTaxRate}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}


Filter function

def updatevariable(value, arg):
    TotalTax = value + float(arg)
    return TotalTax
```

Comment: Do not calculate in templates. Put your business logic in a view function.

Comment: but for that I will have to run loop twice once in template file and second time in view file. there is no way to eliminate that?